# How can I find the largest item in a linked list recursively given the head node?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

```
int findLargest (ListNode *p)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Preconditions: list head pointer is passed as a parameter.
// Postconditions: returns the largest value in the linked list.
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    if (p->item != NULL)
    {
        int largest = p->item;
        if (largest > p->next->item)
            ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Is it possible to write this recursive function passing only a pointer as a parameter?  I can't figure out how to do this without adding more parameters.  Any ideas?  I am only using sequential search.  Nothing fancy.

Here is the portion of class List that will be needed:

```
    struct ListNode 
    {
        ListItemType item;  // A data item on the list.
        ListNode    *next;  // Pointer to next node
    }; // end ListNode

    ListNode   *head; // Pointer to linked list of items.
```

I am mainly worried about the **feasibility** of the problem.  Can this be done with only a pointer as a parameter?

Comment: please show the definition of List...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely feasible, although I agree that recursion is not the best solution to solve this problem. In this case, non-recursive code would be easier to read (recursion), faster (overhead of function call), and more memory efficient (obviously more stack frames).

Each recursive call returns the greater of either it's value or the value from the rest of the list.

```
int findLargest (ListNode *p) {
    int current = p->item;
    int next;

    if (p->next == NULL) {
        //The value at this node is obviously larger than a non-existent value
        return current;
    } else {
        //Recur to find the highest value from the rest of the LinkedList
        next = findLargest(p->next);
    }

    //Return the highest value between this node and the end of the list
    if (current > next) {
        return current;
    } else {
        return next;
    }
}
```

Recursion stops when the `next` item is null.

Comment: I disagree with your characterization of a recursive solution on all accounts. Recursion is certainly the **most idiomatic**, straightforward solution to this inherently recursive problem. It is also very *readable* (arguably much more so than the iterative variant). Any modern C++ compiler will *completely* remove the recursive function calls, so there is no overhead – hence the recursive solution is also *efficient*, both in terms of time and memory. **Your** recursive solution, on the other hand, actually has all the disadvantages you mentioned.

Comment: I wrote mine to be as readable as possible, considering this is a homework question. How does your one line implementation of this *same algorithm* achieve different runtime characteristics? I've never studied CS (compilers) nor have I ever coded C/C++ professionally.

Comment: The issue with your code is that it doesn’t show the recursive structure well. A recursion always consists of two parts, the base case and the recurrence. Glancing on your code it’s not clear where they are. Whereas my implementation directly corresponds to the mathematical formulation of the problem (not the solution: the problem!). Your code’s verbosity clouds the underlying algorithm, rather than clarifying it. The comments, in particular, don’t add any explanation (except for the first one). As for performance, consider Roger’s first implementation which is tail recursive (=> wikipedia).

Comment: Furthermore, your initial comment (“I agree that recursion is not the best solution to solve this problem”) indicates how your code fails to represent the structure of the problem directly, since a recursive solution *is* appropriate here: a good recursive solution just needs to paraphrase the question to solve it (see again my answer which brings the mathematical problem formulation and the recursive implementation face to face).

Answer (score 5):

Though tail-recursion optimization isn't required by C, if you can transform it into tail-recursion (and you can without a lot of work here), then, when that optimization is applied, you can maintain the readability, clarity, and conciseness of recursion with the *same* performance (time and space) as the best non-recursive solution.

I've slightly modified the function's conditions so it can work on an empty list with no nodes (where *p* is null) and will return null in that case.  This is tail-recursive, and does require another parameter:

```
ListNode* findLargestRecurse(ListNode* p, ListNode* largest) {
  // this is an implementation detail, and would not be called directly
  // requires that largest is not null, but p may be null
  if (!p) return largest;
  if (p->item > largest->item) largest = p;
  return findLargestRecurse(p->next, largest);
}

// preconditions: list head pointer is passed as a parameter, and may be null
// postcondition: returns the node with the largest value, or null
ListNode* findLargest(ListNode* p) {
  if (!p) return 0; // mark A, see below
  return findLargestRecurse(p->next, p);
}
```

Notice you use the main entry, *findLargest*, to setup the initial conditions/context for the actual recursion, *findLargestRecurse*.

However, I'd write that tail-recursion as an iterative while loop to rely less on what's currently both very compiler-specific and generally unfamiliar in C, which is not hard to do:

```
// preconditions: list head pointer is passed as a parameter, and may be null
// postcondition: returns the node with the largest value, or null
ListNode* findLargest(ListNode* p) {
  ListNode* largest = 0;
  for (; p; p = p->next) {
    if (!largest || p->item > largest->item) {
      largest = p;
    }
  }
  return largest;
}
```

You can separate out the `!largest` condition from the loop by doing it beforehand, by checking a base case just like the first *findLargest* does ("mark A").

And looking at this now, you may wonder why I called the recursive version more concise: it really isn't for this trivial example.  That's partially because C is designed to favor iteration (notice the for loop in particular), somewhat because I tried to be verbose in the recursion instead of squashing it down as I would normally (so you could understand it easier), and the rest is because this is just a simple problem.

Comment: Your recursive solution is confusing – you don’t actually need that accumulator and it doesn’t add any clarity. Matthieu’s answer is also tail recursive and doesn’t need that extra parameter.

Comment: @Konrad: Matthieu's answer is *not* tail recursive.  Notice it does something with the result of the recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

I find that most recursive problems can be solved using the framework/template of thinking about:

- What information do I have at hand right now?
- What information will I get if I make a recursive call?
- How can I combine those two to make a final result?
- (Also, be sure to be clear about the 'base case'.)

In this case, the answers are

- the value in the current node
- the largest element in the 'suffix' of the list that comes after this node
- hmmm, that's for you to figure out
- (What should you return for the empty list?  Does the homework say?)

Have fun.  :)

Comment: For an empty list it doesn't say.  Maybe I should put a precondition that there is at least one item or throw an exception.

Comment: If this is e.g. a list of non-negative integers, the easiest thing will be to return a negative value for the empty list (this will make the 'combine' step easier to code).

Answer (score 3):

I have seen some code posted and could not refrain to add my own... because I really think it could be done more simply :)

I suppose that `item` is of a numeric type.

```
#include <algorithm> // std::max
#include <limits>    // std::numeric_limits

ListItemType findLargest(const ListNode* p)
{
  if (p == 0)
    return std::numeric_limits<ListItemType>::min();
  else
    return std::max(p->item, findLargest(p->next));
}
```

As you can see, much simpler, and I took the liberty to add a `const` since we're certainly not going to have to modify the list itself!

Comment: Remember how you were told to avoid run-on sentences in grammar class because they get too long winded and you can't tell exactly what's going on and a ternary might be nice to put it all in one line but who cares about lines and it really wouldn't be an improvement to use the conditional operator instead because this is fine.

Comment: I second Roger here. I rarely use the ternary operator apart from the `bool i; std::cout << "foo is " << (i ? " not": "") << "a muppet";`. The goal is not to minimize the amount of lines (it's a mean) but to minimize the time spent reading and analyzing (maintenance).

Answer (score 2):

**Java Version**

```
return max(head, head.value);
int max(Node node, int currentMax)
{
    if(node==null)
        return currentMax;
    if(node.value>currentMax)
        return max(node.next, node.value);
    else
        return max(node.next, currentMax);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to return just the largest value, then yes you pretty much already have it written.

```
int FindLargest(ListNode* node){
  if (node != NULL){
    int downTheListLargest = FindLargest(node->next);
    if (downTheListLargest > node->item){
      return downTheListLargest;
    }
    return node->item;
  }
  return //?? some max negative value
}
```

If you are looking to return a pointer to the largest node, then the parameter needs to be a double pointer (**), or the function needs to return a pointer.

```
ListNode* FindLargest(ListNode* node){
  if (node == NULL){
    return NULL;
  }
  ListNode* downTheListLargestNode = FindLargest(node->next);
  if (downTheListLargestNode && downTheListLargestNode->item > node->item){
    return downTheListLargestNode;
  }
  return node;
}
```

Really there is no reason to do this recursively.  I assume this is just an exercise to learn about recursion, but I feel it is a poor learning example.

Comment: This doesn't work (it recurses until node==NULL, then downTheListLargest gets dereferenced and crashes).  This is also tagged as homework.

Comment: Ok - fixed end of list issue.  I have seen two schools of thought on the homework questions 1) answer it anyways so stack overflow has the question answered -or- 2) try to educate the student rather than handing out an answer.... Which is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another idiomatic recursive solution, similar to Matthieu’s. Unlike his solution, this one requires an empty list – arguably, taking the smallest item of an empty list isn’t a meaningful operation:

```
// Precondition: list is non-empty.
int find_largest(ListNode const* n) {
    assert(n != 0 && "find_largest requires non-empty list.");
    return n->next == 0 ? n->item
                        : max(n->item, find_largest(n->next));
}
```

This one reads much like a mathematical definition, using the “cases” notation:

```
             { item(i),                   if i is the last node
largest(i) = {
             { max{item(i), largest(i+1)} else.
```

Comment: I kind of feel proud being cited by someone having 10 times my rep (and more) :) I would still however maintain 2 things: 1/ `const` keyword and 2/ no precondition (or at the very least, an assert).

Comment: @Matthieu: you're right of course. I didn’t put in the assert because C++’ builtin `assert` macro is quite a weak mechanism and I use other techniques in practice.

Comment: Operating on an empty list may not be a meaningful operation, but it's mathematically convenient for that to be a *defined* operation, rather than a prerequisite that must be continually checked before calling.

Comment: On another note, I personally find the comment for the precondition perfectly fine for example code (so completely agree with you there), but I do sometimes use asserts (even C's limited assert) in example code as a placeholder for better techniques.

Comment: I was being a nitpick :) I also find that `assert` is really weak and use a custom made macro in real code that does a bit more (line and file, throw exception instead of aborting, carries a message, ...)

Answer (score 0):

No need for recursion, and your example isn't recursion (it would have to call itself).

It is possible to do this with only a pointer as a parameter.

Hint: Assign p to p->next to advance through the list.

Answer (score 0):

Always break recursion problems into two steps: the stop condition and "the rest of the problem". Start by thinking about the stop condition. In linked lists it's usually the null node. But in your case, think what happens when the given node is null. What would you return? The truth is that you have to return the max value no matter what, and when there are no elements in the list there is *no* max element. In this case maybe you can just assume that a list must therefore have at least one element.

So what's the stop condition? The stop condition is when there's a single element in the list; and in this case the max value is that node's value.

The next step is the recursive step. Suppose you have an element linked to a list. And pay attention how I describe a linked list: a node linked to a linked list. The max value is the value of that node if it's larger than the largest value of the list, or the largest value of the list otherwise.